# Facebook SDK - Profile picture is throwing an unwrapping error

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I use Parse with Facebook login so if I try to get the profile picture of the logged in user I get the error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I think the version of the SDK must be v4.5.1, and I use the Xcode 7 beta with Swift 2.

I use the code below to get the job done, but it won't run.

```
let pictureRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture?type=large&redirect=false", parameters: ["fields": "url"])
pictureRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        print("\(result)")
        if let dictPic = result as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            print(dictPic)
            let url: String = dictPic["data{url}"] as AnyObject? as! String // <- this line is causing the error
            print(url)
            let URLRequest = NSURL(string: url)
            let URLRequestNeeded = NSURLRequest(URL: URLRequest!)                                  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(URLRequestNeeded, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            let picture = self.scaleImageWith(UIImage(data: data!)!, and: CGSizeMake(75, 75))
            let pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture)
            let endPicture = PFFile(data: pictureData!)
            PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(endPicture, forKey: "picture")
            PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()

        })
    }
} else {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

Comment: Could you send a screenshot or tell the line which is causing the error? I would say it is caused when you try to parse some specific value from Facebook response...

Comment: I did now :) It crashes there where I try to get the URL of the picture.